# How to Delete channel type Events-Store in kubemq

Tags: publish-subscribe, messagebroker

How to Clear or Delete channel type Events-Store in kubemq. Have a need to delete channel after expire date or set time for delete channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is automatically deleted. The default time is 24 h of inactivity,
and can configure this to any value in config.